# How can a python function put all its variables in the global namespace?

Tags: python, metaclass

It is possible (though normally not a good idea) to create a class that stores its member definitions in `globals()` or another dictionary:

```
oddclass = type("oddclass", (object,), globals())
```

Is there a way to do the same with a function, so that all its local variables are stored in the global (or module) namespace, rather than its own?

I can get the same effect one variable at a time, by declaring variables `global`:

```
def myfunction():
    global x
    x = 10
```

What I'm looking for is a **general** way to achieve the same effect for all the internal variables of `myfunction` (also for those not yet declared at the top), ideally some sort of one-liner that can easily be added and then removed when it's no longer needed.

PS. I'm asking this question because I'm curious about the way python manages function namespaces. My motivation is to use this as a *temporary* debugging aid in certain circumstances (a function with a lot of local data that fails mysteriously), but never mind that: I can live with using `global` as above. This question is about python function internals.

Comment: Why do you want your functions to behave in a totally different way when they are being debugged? You risk the `x` from one function interfering with another.

Comment: Why not use the debugger as a debugging aid?

Comment: If a function raises an exception in the middle of managing a complex data structure, the debugger bundled with IDLE is not up to the task of examining the leftovers. (Indeed a decent debugger would make this uncenessary). But global variables can be examined from the interpreter prompt. I only do this (manually) for the one function that's about to crash, so there's no risk down the road.

Comment: I've debugged a lot of Python, but never had to do that. But then I developed my own debugger and automated means to invoke it. See: http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdebugger%2Fpycopia

Comment: Interesting... well, then you must agree that the built-in debugger leaves something to be desired! :-)

Comment: Yes... and also IDLE. ;) I use exclusively Vim editor with custom Vim helper functions (using Vim's embedded Python), custom shell script helpers, and custom debugger, on Linux.

Comment: If your functions crash - the **proper** procedure is to add _try_/_except_ blocks. You may "export" your locals from exception point.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
>>> def test():
    x = 10
    y = 'Some string'
    for k, v in locals().items():
        globals()[k] = v


>>> test()

>>> x
10
>>> y
'Some string'
```

Just keep in mind that this is **very unsafe technique and should never be used**.

Comment: Thanks but this simply _copies_ the values to the global namespace; if the value changes or if I define more variables, the global value won't track them.

Comment: @alexis That's not quite right. This points names in the global namespace at the local variables. If you change one of them, i.e. `z = []` then `globals['z'] = z` then `z.append(1)`, it will be reflected. Only if you __replace__ one of them, by pointing a name at a new object, i.e. `x += 1` or `y.replace(' ', '_')`, will it not be reflected. A simpler version would be `globals().update(locals())`.

Comment: You want locals from function to be seen in the global space. How can local values be changed without calling the function?
Besides, local variables are destroyed when you leave the function; anyone dealing with code should know that. You may preserve their value by technique I suggested, but the variable itself are non-existent - they are created on the stack and are cleared on function return.

Comment: @agf, thanks I understand all this. Any assignment to the local names also breaks the correspondence. Declaring the variables I want to track as `global` is far more robust. But I'm asking this question because I'm pretty sure I've seen it done, and I'm curious as to how.

Comment: @volcano, local variables will be changed because my function is more than two lines long. And nothing is destroyed if the variables are stored in the global namespace. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @alexis The moment interpreter sees assignment, it creates a local variable - unless you precede it's declaration with "global" modifier. I strongly doubt that you may overcome that.
On the other hand, any mutable object (integers, tuples and strings are not mutable) may be updated within procedure from the global scope. You'll just have to initiate your objects before function call.